# Selected/Unselected UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

The problem is I tried to change the image of my button when button is selected but it only changes the last button. I actually found the below code in another stackoverflow question but it does not work.(I created my button programmatically)

```
var buttonSelect = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 340, y: 40, width: 40, height: 21))
var s = 1

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstSection", for: indexPath) as? ShopTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("error")
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        buttonSelect.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShopTableViewController.btnChoose), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonSelect.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.contentView.addSubview(buttonSelect)
    }
}

@IBAction  func btnAdd (_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttonSelect = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 280, y: 10, width: 40, height: 21))
    buttonSelect.setImage(UIImage(named : "buttontick"), for: .normal)

    //I add my button in each cell every time I pressed add button

    //other codes...
}


@IBAction func btnChoose(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if buttonSelect == sender {
        if s % 2 == 0 {
            buttonSelect.setImage(UIImage(named : "notclicked"), for: .normal)
            s = s + 1
        } else {
            buttonSelect.setImage(UIImage(named : "buttontick"), for: .normal)
            s = s + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it only changes the last button`, which buttons would you like to change?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using a `UITableViewController` so if that's true it would probably help to show that code code.

Comment: Please give us more of your code, and more of your intended functionality.

Comment: I created cells in my table view then when I pressed add button it creates new cells with buttons and what I want is when I pressed the inner buttons it must change its image but it only changes the last cells' button @Ladislav

Comment: can you share your project using github or any other hosting site?

Comment: Yes I am using UITableViewController @Jim

Comment: Problem is that you are using `buttonSelect` as an instance var in `UITableViewController`, you should instead create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that contains the button, in your code currently `buttonSelect` is the last dequeued cell's button which is probably not what you want...

Answer (score -2):

```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_radio_button_unchecked"), for: .normal)
    setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_radio_button_checked"), for: .selected)

    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ToggleButton.tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  @objc func tapped() {
    self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
  }
```